# Is there a way to force my SAML service provider WebApp to use HTTP-POST instead of a Redirect?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

the IdP that I am using has 2 different locations for it's `SingleSignOnService` and they are:

```
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://rengirtu.sciedu.jp/sub/Redirect/SSO"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://rengirtu.sciedu.jp/sub/POST/SSO"/>
```

When my SP web app connects, it always uses the `HTTP-Redirect` address(https://rengirtu.sciedu.jp/sub/Redirect/SSO).

Is there a way to force ITfoxTec to use the `HTTP-POST` address(https://rengirtu.sciedu.jp/sub/POST/SSO) instead?

Here is the code for the ITfoxTec Login() method I am using:

```
[Route("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
        {
            //ForceAuthn = true,
            //Subject = new Subject { NameID = new NameID { ID = "Japan_Portal" } },
            //NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy { AllowCreate = true, Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" },
            //Extensions = new AppExtensions(),
            //RequestedAuthnContext = new RequestedAuthnContext
            //{
            //    Comparison = AuthnContextComparisonTypes.Exact,
            //    AuthnContextClassRef = new string[] { AuthnContextClassTypes.PasswordProtectedTransport.OriginalString },
            //},
        }).ToActionResult();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login part looks fine to me, but check the SingleSignOnDestination in the service configuration; I had to make some changes there to select the right url. I think the sample just selects the first url in the metadata regardless of method.

```
Uri postBinding = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices
        .Single(b => b.Binding == postBinding).Location;
```